# Javascript number conversion

Tags: javascript, double-precision, largenumber

why the conversion fail?

```
var ccc=10206229832728593;
alert("saveme.php?id="+ccc.toString() ) ;

var ccc=10152714408613803;
alert("saveme.php?id="+ccc.toString() ) ;
```

the first var is decreased by 1 and the second one is increased by 1.
I'm going crazy! what i wrong?

Comment: You do not need to convert to a string. JavaScript will do that for you. `toString()` isn't causing this problem in this case.

Comment: please try... even without conversion it fail 

 var ccc=10206229832728593;
 alert("saveme.php?id="+ccc ) ;

Comment: I've noticed, just as baffled as you are.

Comment: `ccc = "10206229832728593";` works though. Quick read: solution for numbers greater than 15 zeros: wrap as string.

Comment: yes, adding quotes it works :)